# AppExchange App

Tags: appexchange, app

Would it be possible to embedded an app exchange app in another App Exhcange app? I'm building an app that uses a component from the app exchange and I was wondering if it would be possible to upload this application to the AppExchange(depends from another app exchange app as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can create Extension Apps that depend on another app. All you do is install the dependent app (1st Generation Packaging) and create your app, or specify the other app as a dependency (2nd Generation Packaging). I don't have all the details, but presumably, you will likely need the cooperation of the dependent package's developer, if that's not yourself, and you'll have to justify your dependency during the Security Review. All that said, if you have a legitimate use case, it is technologically possible.